Nonseparating immersed surface and second homology
Given a closed, connected orientable 3-manifold $M$ and a two-sided, connected, closed immersed surface $\Sigma$ which is nonseparating in $M$. Does this mean that the second homology of $M$ is non trivial? Clearly this is the case when the surface is embedded. Does immersion change anything here?
According to FOLIATIONS AND THE TOPOLOGY OF 3-MANIFOLDS by Gabai there exists an embedded surface representing the same homology class as $\Sigma$ (Corollary 6.18). But does this imply that this embedded surface is non-separating as well, i.e. the homology class is non-trivial?

Ok so I was thinking if we pick a neighborhood of a point on $\Sigma$ such that the restriction to that neighborhood is an embedding, then this embedding is also nonseparating and thus represents a nontrivial element in $H_2(M)$ which would mean that nonseparating immersed surface implies non-trivial second Homology. Is my argumentation correct?

Do you know how to prove the claim for embedded surfaces?

I think one constructs a loop that intersects the surface in a single point and then has that the intersection of homology classes is non trivial. Can we argue the same way for immersed surfaces?

Why not?........

I assumed that this would be the case but I was not sure if immersion might cause some problems I didn’t consider

Well, write down a detailed proof in the embedded case and then repeat this proof in the immersed case. If you encounter difficulties, ask a more focused questions. In the end, if you were to succeed in reading Gabai's papers, you have to be proficient in tasks like this.

Not really, I was merely using Gabai's results. The problem I have is with the homology classes on the immersed surface and possible self intersections of the surface. Do these intersections have any effect on the homology classes and the differences to the case of embedded surfaces?

I can only repeat my previous suggestion.

Ok let me try again: The way I understand the proof in the embedded case is that we have a loop on our embedded surface that is intersected by a loop that intersects the surface exactly once and thus these homology classes are not trivial. Now if we have an immersion, the loop that intersects the surface once is totally fine, but what about the loop on the surface? Does this loop exist because locally around a point the immersion is an embedding? Or am I completely on a wrong path here?
